# Is an irreducible analytic subset locally complete intersects at general point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $X$ be an reduced and  irreducible complex analytic space of dimension $m$ and $Z$ an $n$-dimensional irreducible analytic subset of $X$ with reduced structure.

Then we say that  ***$Z$   locally complete intersect at $x\in Z$*** if there exists an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $X$ such that the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_Z$
is generated by a regular sequence of length $m-n$   on $U_x$.  (Note: This condition may be equivalent to $\mathcal{I}_{Z,x}$ being generated by a regular sequence of length $m-n$.)

**Question:**  **Is $Z$ locally complete intersects at the general point of $Z$?** (general points means $Z$ minus some proper analytic subset of $Z$)

One can   freely impose conditions to discuss this issue. Any comments and clues will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you agree that the condition is clearly satisfied at a point $z\in Z$ if $X$ and $Z$ are both smooth at $z$?

Comment: @KReiser   Yes.  If we assume that the support of $Z$ lies in the singular locus of $X$, what happens?

Comment: Probably nothing good - consider $(0,0)$ on $V(y^2-x^3)$. Locally this can't be cut out by a single function.